# Is it possible to debug .net core with Rider and launchSettings - executable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, .net-core, rider

I have following launchSettings.json file in my .NET Core 2.2 project:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "ProfileName": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "dotnet",
      "commandLineArgs": "path\to\external\assembly.dll -p path\to\my\assembly.dll"
    }
  }
}
```

Idea is to kick off dotnet to run external assembly with `-p path\to\my\assembly.dll` param to run code from my assembly in the end.

Problem: **I'm unable to run it with attached debugger in Rider.**

I can just run it, it starts fine. And I can attach debugger manually with `Ctrl+Alt+F5`.

In Visual Studio I can run it with debugger attached.

When I create Run/Debug configuration `.NET Executable` in Rider, starting stucks without any errors.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I started it as .Net Executable.

The idea is to **not mention dotnet explicitly** and **set working directory to external assembly**.

So, my .Net Executable config looks like this:

- Exe path: path\to\external\assembly.dll
- Program Arguments: -p path\to\my\assembly.dll
- Working Directory: path\to\external\